# Regex Sub and Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am struggling replacing a string in a pandas cell with data from a dictionary. I have a pandas frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

f = {'GAAP':['<1>','2','3','4'],'CP':['5','6','<7>','8']}
filter = pd.DataFrame(data=f)
filter
```

and a dictionary:

```
d = {'GAAP':['100','101'],'CP':['500','501','502']}
d
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
op = {'GAAP':['100|101','2','3','4'],'CP':['5','6','500|501|502','8']}
op = pd.DataFrame(data=op)
op
```

I tried something like:

```
def rep1(fr,di):
op=re.sub('\<.*?\>',fr,di)
return(op)


a='|'.join(d['GAAP'])
op=rep1(filter['GAAP'],a)
op
```

but get an error saying series objects are mutable and cannot be hashed.Any suggestions  on what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try use `pd.to_numeric` convert the <> to NaN, then `fillna`

```
filter=filter.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').fillna(pd.Series(d).str.join('|'))
      GAAP           CP
0  100|101            5
1        2            6
2        3  500|501|502
3        4            8
```

Comment: you got me exactly what I asked for. However, I guess I should have been more clearer in the ask. What if the filter has strings ?

Comment: @NumberLogic using `filter.mask(filter.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('<'))).fillna(pd.Series(d).str.join('|'))
`

Comment: @NumberLogic BTW , would you like consider to accept it ?

Comment: Tried to accept it as soon as i realized how elegant a solution you came up with ! Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

one way about it using **[replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)** : get the regexes that match the <> and pair them with their replacements from the dictionary.

```
outcome = filter.replace({'GAAP':"\<\d\>", 'CP':"\<\d\>"},
           {"GAAP":"|".join(d['GAAP']), "CP":"|".join(d["CP"])},
           regex=True)

    GAAP    CP
0   100|101 5
1   2       6
2   3      500|501|502
3   4       8
```